# Create a foreign key to system tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sysobjects

I want to create table with to columns:

```
IdRole
IdProcedure
```

the idea is that `IdProcedure` is a FK to `sys.objects`.

When I create this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type='p'
```

it works fine, but this one:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CORE_ProcedureXRole
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SysProcedure
FOREIGN KEY (IdProcedure)
REFERENCES sys.objects(object_id)
```

tells me:

> Foreign key 'FK_SysProcedure' references invalid table
>   'sys.objects'.

Comment: `sys.objects` is a view not a table. You can't create FKs to system objects anyway.

Comment: ok thanks.. I wasnt sure if I could do it..

Comment: Why would you want to do this? For one it would prevent drop/re-create since a new object_id is randomly assigned. Maybe you could tell us what problem you're trying to solve instead of telling us that you want to solve it with a foreign key to sys.objects.

Comment: If you're going to add this reference, I'd suggest cascading deletes, so that you don't get all hung up when an object gets removed from sys.objects which has a child record in your user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.objects` isn't a table. It's a system view backed by data stored in proprietary SQL Server format. If you want to make sure that the stored name is correct, add a `TRIGGER` for update and insert to handle the checking.